# Bijection $f$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ divides $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-proofs

> Is it possible to construct a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ divides $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

At first, I've tried to construct such function but without any success. So now I'm convinced that such $f$ does not exist, but I could not solve it using the standard approaches/tricks in these kinds of problems. So, what is the trick that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Assume we have constructed $f(k)$ for all $k<n$. Then there are infinitely many naturals $x$ with $n\mid\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)+x$. Let $f(n)$ be the smallest such $x$ that is $\notin\{f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)\}$. This way we obtain an *injective* map $f$ with the required divisibility property. Can one show that  this map is also *onto*?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Suppose that $a \not\in f(\mathbb{N})$. Then, we did not choose $x=a$ at any step, so there exists an $N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$, $n$ does not divide $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)-a$. Is it now possible to extract a contradiction from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a sequence can in fact be constructed.  Suppose $f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)$ have been chosen, and let $a$ be distinct from all of these.  We show how to force either $f(n)=a$ or $f(n+1)=a$.  If, for example, we always force the smallest $a$ which is not in the range, we will end up with a bijection.

Let $S=f(1)+\cdots+f(n-1)$; there are two possibilities.  If $S+a\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod } n)$, we can choose $f(n)=a$.  If not, we set $f(n)=kn-S$ for some integer $k$, where $k\equiv a\ (\textrm{mod }(n+1))$, and we will then choose $f(n+1)=a$.  Then $f(1)+\cdots+f(n)=kn$, so the divisibility condition holds at $n$; we can choose $k$ as large as we want to ensure $f(n)$ is distinct from $f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)$.

Finally,
$$f(1)+\cdots+f(n+1)=kn+a \equiv -a+a \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod }(n+1)),$$
so the divisibility condition holds here as well.

If we make the minimum choice at each step, we obtain a bijection which begins like this:
$1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 52, 5, 43, 6, 54, 7, 65, 8, 76, 9, 103, 11, 99, 12, 110,\cdots$